# Implement Tag system that using existing Tag that was added before

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET 5, MVC6 and EF7 to create website that collecting Grammar of language, one Grammar can have many Tag(Tag is used to indicate something like level, meaning, etc.) and one Tag can be used in many Grammar.

When I add Grammar then attach Tag to it, I want existing Tags(that was added in first time) to be pointed from Grammar instead of add new tag every time I add grammar(later I plan to implement auto-complete when user typing Tag the same way like SO).

These are models and context that I use, I implemented many-to-many by read from http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many.

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<GrammarTag> GrammarTags { get; set; }
}

public class Grammar
{
    public int GrammarId { get; set; }
    public List<GrammarTag> GrammarTags { get; set; }
        ....
}

public class GrammarTag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public int GrammarId { get; set; }
    public Grammar Grammar { get; set; }
}
```

And OnModelCreating in ApplicationDbContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<GrammarTag>().HasKey(g => new { g.GrammarId, g.TagId });

        builder.Entity<Tag>()
            .HasMany(t => t.GrammarTags)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.Entity<Grammar>()
            .HasMany(g => g.GrammarTags)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.Entity<GrammarTag>()
            .HasOne(gt => gt.Grammar)
            .WithMany(g => g.GrammarTags)
            .HasForeignKey(gt => gt.GrammarId);

        builder.Entity<GrammarTag>()
            .HasOne(gt => gt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.GrammarTags)
            .HasForeignKey(gt => gt.TagId);

    }
```

In Create method in controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AddGrammarViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!User.IsSignedIn())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
            }

            var grammar = new Grammar()
            {
                 ....
            };
            // in viewmodel, Tag is string and is delimited each Tag by comma
            var tags = viewmodel.Tags.Split(',');
            var tagList = new List<Tag>();

            foreach (var tag in tags)
            {
                if (_context.Tag.Any(t => t.Text == tag))
                {
                    tagList.Add(_context.Tag.Single(t => t.Text == tag));
                }
                else
                {
                    tagList.Add(new Tag { Text = tag });
                }
            }

            var grammaTagList = new List<GrammarTag>();

            foreach (var tag in tagList)
            {
                grammaTagList.Add(new GrammarTag { Tag = tag, Grammar = grammar });
            }

            _context.Grammar.Add(grammar);
            _context.Tag.AddRange(tagList);
            _context.GrammarTag.AddRange(grammaTagList);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

The problem is when I add Grammar that use same Tag that was added before, I got database error `SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tag' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`.
I thought it because I use the same Tag that was query from database but it is the way I want so I can't figure out how can I implement this Tag system.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to re-insert a tag that has already been created into the database. If the tag already exists, you should just leave it (or maybe update it as needed). If you try and add it again, with the same ID, it will error because IDs must be unique.

Comment: @Jonathan So how can I add it relationship to Grammar, Can I just put the existing Tags to new GrammarTag and add only new Tags to _context.Tag?

Comment: You only need an explicit entity for the relationship (i.e. `GrammarTag`) if you're including a payload (additional data on the relationship), which you are not doing here. Your life and code would be greatly simplified if you just use an implicit join table. In other words, `Tag` would have a property `public virtual ICollection<Grammar> { get; set; }` and `Grammar` would have a property `public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }`. EF can handle this natively so there's no need for fluent config, and the LINQ queries are *much* simpler.

Comment: @ChrisPratt When I used implicit join table(deleted all fluent config and use collecting navigation properties as you said), I got `The navigation 'Tags' on entity type 'Grammar' has not been added to the model, or ignored, or target entityType ignored.`, it because EF7 doesn't support implicit join table[issue#1368](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1368).

Comment: Wow. Wasn't aware of that. I've been holding off on making the jump because all of these technologies are still very much in infancy. Despite the version numbers, these are all essentially 1.0 releases at best. And, with something as simple as M2M not being supported, I think it's generous to even consider it 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out, the problem is as error message said, it because I'm inserting Tags that was queried from database thus it has identity column(PK).
So, I just have to check if that Tag was added before, then add only new Tags to database, for Tag's  relationship with join table, I just add it to GrammarTag then add all new GrammarTags to database.

```
    var tags = viewmodel.Tags.Split(',');
    // create old tag and new tag list
    var oldTags = new List<Tag>();
    var newTags = new List<Tag>();

    // check old and new tag and add it to list
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        var testTag = await _context.Tag.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Text == tag);

        if (testTag != null)
        {
            oldTags.Add(testTag);
        }
        else
        {
            newTags.Add(new Tag { Text = tag });
        }
    }

    var grammaTagList = new List<GrammarTag>();
    oldTags.AddRange(newTags);

    // put every that in this Grammar to join table
    foreach (var tag in oldTags)
    {
        grammaTagList.Add(new GrammarTag { Tag = tag, Grammar = grammar });
    }

    _context.Grammar.Add(grammar);
    // add only the new tag
    _context.Tag.AddRange(newTags);
    _context.GrammarTag.AddRange(grammaTagList);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```